# Take photo in Android app and save it into gallery

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I am developing an Android app, and at some point I have to take a photo and save it to the gallery. The camera opens and takes the photo but does not save it to the gallery.
Here is my code:

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camara);
        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
    }

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {


        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }


    private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;


    @Override

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {

            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CameraActivity">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can anyone help me? I've searched other similar questions but neither could help me.
Thanks to everyone, and rest of a good day.

Comment: You do not have any code related to saving the image. A camera app does not necessarily save an image when you start it via `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: ok, but how can that help me?

Comment: The thing is, where i can find the code to save the image?

Comment: "where i can find the code to save the image?" -- there is [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics), and there are [books](https://commonsware.com/Android/). Right now, all your code is asking the camera app to do is to give you a low-resolution thumbnail of a photo. You can use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to tell the camera app to save the image in a location of your choosing, using `FileProvider` to ensure that the camera app can write to that location. See [this sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/Camera/FileProvider), for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly create a provider file in your xml folder

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

Here is the code of provider

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Add this Line in your manifest file

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                  android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Create a taking picture intent which will open camera

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

Now get the thumbnail of the clicked image

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

Code for saving picture to gallery, image will be saved in pictures folder

```
String currentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}


static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ...
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                                  "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                                  photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}


private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Code to get picture

```
private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = imageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = imageView.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: where to call the methods createImageFile() dispatchTakePictureIntent() galleryAddPic() setPic(). According to your code they are never called.

Comment: You can set a button and call dispatchTakePictureIntent()