# How to take images in android and save it on gallery as well as in the app-specific storage ? (java, android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to call the camera through intent, capture images, and save it locally in the gallery and in the app-specific storage how can I achieve that?

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60027883/take-photo-in-android-app-and-save-it-into-gallery) question also but the code is not working I don't know why.

Comment: are you running it on Android 12?

Comment: No, I am running it on my emulator and android device both are android 11 @Jabbar

Comment: Do you want to save an image in two locations? And you did not describe any problem you encountered.

Comment: The media store does not scan files in app specific storages. Are you asking it should? Describe your problem!

Comment: since android 11, the scope of the storage has changed. so you need to check what is the version of the android and create the specific path depending on the android version

Comment: Hi, I encountered the same issue , the image has been successfully stored in app-specific scope storage but default gallery cannot scan it. so I have to save it in some shared folder so that any other app can access it. the pic has been taken by default camera using the new Api for that.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something like this Before, I Share my code with you and others that may help.
in this scenario if you want to save captured image, you have to check which api level that device is running with. for api level 28 and below you have to use specific method and for api level 28 above you have specific way.
so first step, start from:
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>
```

and add this line in to your AndroidManifest.xml application tag:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

if your project targetSdkVersion is 28 and above, you have to use **ActivityResultLauncher** otherwise you have to override **onRequestPermissionResult** in your fragment or activity.
if you use fragment you have to register your **ActivityResultLauncher** in onAttach method, if not register it in onCreate of your Activity, so do this:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {
   private Bitmap bitmap;
   private ActivityResultLauncher<String> storageResultActivity;


    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull @NotNull Context context) {
       super.onAttach(context);
       registerWriteExternalStoragePermission();
    }
```

**registerWriteExternalStoragePermission** has this codes:

```
    private void registerWriteExternalStoragePermission() {
    storageResultActivity = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
        if (isGranted) {
            checkStoragePermissionAndSaveImage(bitmap);
        }
    });
}
```

so next step is to get back result of captured image from intent and change it to Bitmap for this section we need another **activityResultLauncher** so do this in onAttach of your fragment or onCreate of your activity:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
    if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
       Intent data = result.getData();
       if (data == null || data.getData() == null) {
          //showError
       }
       Uri uri = data.getData();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 29) {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri);
        } else {
            ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(context.getContentResolver(), uri);
            bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
        }
    }
```

so next step is to check your app has storage permission or not:

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        saveImageInAndroidApi28AndBelow(bitmap);
    } else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(requireActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        //show user app can't save image for storage permission denied
    } else {
        storageResultActivity.launch(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
```

ok as we near the end of this answer :) you have to implement **saveImageInAndroidApi28AndBelow** method, se lets go to do it:

```
    private boolean saveImageInAndroidApi28AndBelow(Bitmap bitmap) {
    OutputStream fos;
    String imagesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString();
    File image = new File(imagesDir, "IMG_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(image);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 95, fos);
        Objects.requireNonNull(fos).close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //isSuccess = false;
        return false;
    }
    //isSuccess = true;
    return true;
}
```

and the final step is to implement **saveImageInAndroidApi29AndAbove** method do it like this:

```
@NonNull
public Uri saveImageInAndroidApi29AndAbove(@NonNull final Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
    final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "IMG_" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    }
    final ContentResolver resolver = requireContext().getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = null;
    try {
        final Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        uri = resolver.insert(contentUri, values);
        if (uri == null) {
            //isSuccess = false;
            throw new IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.");
        }
        try (final OutputStream stream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri)) {
            if (stream == null) {
                //isSuccess = false;
                throw new IOException("Failed to open output stream.");
            }
            if (!bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 95, stream)) {
                //isSuccess = false;
                throw new IOException("Failed to save bitmap.");
            }
        }
        //isSuccess = true;
        return uri;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (uri != null) {
            resolver.delete(uri, null, null);
        }
        throw e;
    }
}
```

so you have to check which API Level that device is running and with with little code handle what you want:

```
            if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            try {
                saveImageInAndroidApi29AndAbove(bitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
               //show error to user that operatoin failed
            }
        } else {
            saveImageInAndroidApi28AndBelow(bitmap);
        }
```

**Don't FORGET TO call .launch ON YOUR ActivityResultLauncher**

have a good time with the codes :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the app-specific storage is some sort of cache, in your `onActivityResult()` wouldn't you save the picture first to app-specific storage and  then copy it to `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES`?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, make a Launcher attach the camera and gallery and you have everything in one place, here I send you 2 links to make a launcher

https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358

https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@ideba/how-to-build-a-custom-android-launcher-and-home-screen-application-part-1

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you take a photo from the device, you the image uri in the `onActivityResult`. Now to save it to another location, you can use the code given below

```
void savefile(Uri sourceuri){
    String sourceFilename= sourceuri.getPath();
    String destinationFilename = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+File.separatorChar+"abc.mp3";

    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

    try {
      bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFilename));
      bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destinationFilename, false));
      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
      bis.read(buf);
      do {
         bos.write(buf);
      } while(bis.read(buf) != -1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try {
        if (bis != null) bis.close();
        if (bos != null) bos.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

And in the `onActivityResult`, you can call it like this

```
saveFile(data.getData());
```